# StringWriter in windows universal app

Tags: c#, wpf, input, universal, stringwriter

I am absolutely new to programming.

I'm trying to create a very simple app with three TextBoxes and one final TextBlock. I want to save the input from these three TextBoxes locally so I can read and display it in a TextBlock on the bottom of the page in one string.

[image: Screenshot]

I have read that the StreamWriter class is what I should be using. I just don't know where to start...

There's basically not a lot of code so far really

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        string name = tbxName.Text;
        string age = tbxAge.Text;
        string dinner = tbxDinner.Text;

        string[] answer = { name, age, dinner };

        StringWriter saveText = new StringWriter();
        StringReader readText = new StringReader(answer.ToString());
    }
}
```

How do I store the input of each TextBox and read and display that input in one string in my TextBlock at the bottom of the page?

I want the app to save and to be able to display the input after the app has been closed and reopened again.

Sorry, I know this is super simple stuff...

Comment: Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and choose Properties. Then use the **Settings** tab to create your application settings. A settings.settings file will be created. Based on which the changes will be amended even after the application closes and reopened.

Answer (score 1):

For UWP, we are going to save the our data in ApplicationData in the localfolder. We will the StreamWriter to write a filestream and StreamReader to read from the same stream.

Go and read more about [ApplicationData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)

First create a class to capture all the variables you need declared from the UI.

```
public class Entity
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string dinner { get; set; }
}
```

Now lets get to submitting to contents from the UI to the applicationData storage.

```
using System.IO
OnClickEvent()
{
    Entity ent = new Entity();
    ent.name = tbxName.Text;
    ent.age = int.Parse(tbxAge.Text);
    ent.dinner = tbxDinner.Text;

    //save
        var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("[PUT-HERE-NAME].txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myStream))
        {
            var results = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ent);

            writer.Write(results);
        }
}
```

Lets now work on reading the written data from storage. We are now going to use Stream Reader.

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
OnClickEvent
{
    Entity ent = new Entity();
    string content = string.Empty;
        var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        var stream = await localFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("test.txt");
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            ent= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(content);

        }
}
```

After being able to read, you can display the data to the user now.

```
tbxName.Text = ent.name;
tbxAge.Text = ent.age.ToString();
tbxDinner.Text = ent.dinner
```

Feel free to ask if you ran to any problem or dont understand something.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save the input from these three TextBoxes locally

locally, you means in a file? If yes, you can save one array item per line, to do so:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("textfile.txt", answer);
```

and then, at other moment, you can create the `answer` again:

```
string[] answer = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("textfile.txt");
```

Edit:
Since you are developing a phone app, its better to use `StorageFile`:

```
StorageFolder folder =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile =
    await folder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, string.Join(";", answer));
```

This will save answer in a file with data separated by `;`

To read back:

```
string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
string answer = text.Split(';');
```

Comment: Does that (creating a .txt file) apply for universal apps also since they're sandboxed? Is that the common way of saving text on phone apps?

Comment: it depends on which type of data you want to save: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680266(v=pandp.11).aspx